# how memory allocation is done

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I am expecting NULL pointer exception but I am getting output 222. How is this working.

```
int main()
{
    int *p = (int*)malloc(0);
    *p = 222;
    cout << *p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's implementation-defined if [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) returns a null pointer or not when allocating zero bytes. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

The behaviour of `malloc` with 0 passed is *implementation defined*: it *can* return 0 *or* a pointer. If it returns a pointer, then you must pass that pointer to `free`, but you must *not* deference that pointer.

C and C++ do not differ in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting NULL pointer exception

Your expectation is misguided.

Firstly, `malloc` is not guaranteed to retrurn a null pointer when allocating 0 size.

Secondly, indirecting a null pointer (or any pointer returned by `malloc(0)`) is not guaranteed to cause an exception. Instead the behaviour is undefined.